# Fix div width in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, padding

I have a form inside a div('request_info') in bootstrap 5.
I want to override min-width(of the div) but it doesn't work.
My code:

```
<div class="request_info">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group w-25 p-1 px-5">
          <label for="a"><strong>a</strong></label>
          <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group w-25 p-1 px-5">
            <label for="b"><strong>b</strong></label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="b" required>
        </div>
        <div class="request_submit">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger text-center" name="submit">Make a Request</button>
        </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

in CSS:

```
.request_info {
    min-width: 350px !important;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practise not to use `!important` in a CSS rule according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity.

> !important, however, is bad practice and should be avoided because it
> makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural cascading in
> your stylesheets.

In order to tackle this, you need to increase specificity.

You can do this with many ways.

A simple one is to override `350px` with e.g. `450px` by writing:

```
div.request_info {
    min-width: 450px !important;
   }
```